# how do write update query for unique user name check

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write an update query. In my table `user_name` has to be unique.

So before any `user_name` is updated first I need to check if there doesn't already exist record with that specific `user_name`.

**I wrote a working insert query for that:**

```
INSERT INTO registerlogin 
    (person_name,user_name, user_type,user_password)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT :person_name,:user_name,:login_type,:password) as temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT user_name FROM registerlogin WHERE user_name = :user_name) LIMIT 1
```

How do I modify my update query to achieve same?

**update query:**

```
UPDATE registerlogin 
SET person_name = :person_name,
    user_name = :user_name,
    user_password = :user_password
WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

Comment: Unclear. Do you want to insert when there is no record in table with specific 'user_name' and update if there is?

Comment: not insert i need update after insert record in perversity

Comment: Please share some sample data and required output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
UPDATE registerlogin
SET person_name = :person_name,
user_name = :user_name,
user_password = :user_password
WHERE user_id = :user_id
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registerlogin WHERE user_name = :user_name AND user_id <> :user_id )  < 1
```

In last `where` condition, I checked that record exists with the same `user_name`, if `user_name` exist then `subquery` returns count more than 0 than it will not update record.

Comment: still adding duplicate values?

Comment: What issue you are facing

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE registerlogin 
        SET person_name = :person_name,
        user_name = :user_name,
        user_password = :user_password
        WHERE user_id = :user_id
        AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registerlogin where user_name = :user_name) != 0
```

Comment: Please, add more details.